# UPDATE last 10 records of PHP Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

It seems a simple question but unfortunately I can't find examples.

Suppose that I want use the UPDATE sentence into php for updating the last 10 records of my table "users" of Database "users". what its the code for that? I mean INSERT sentence have a
answer for that using LIMIT etc, but UPDATE dont have it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

pd: For example, I want to update "Firstname" field with "michael" word in the last 10 records.

Comment: SQL has no order unless you specify it. So you need to have a condition that orders the data in your table. What would qualify a row to be one of the last 10 ones? Start with a `SELECT` query that shows the last 10 records. Add that query to your question. That will give you the answer pretty fast.

Comment: Is there any unique auto increment column in users table?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE table SET notes="hi"
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

As per Mysql docs, if there is a unique column, order by  it DESC, and use LIMIT 10 to select last 10 records.

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
        SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
        [WHERE where_condition]
        [ORDER BY ...]
        [LIMIT row_count]
```

Comment: Thanks @rizon the first update sentence works but instead "hi" we have to use 'hi' .

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this.

**Method 1**

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name='value' WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table_name ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0, 10);
```

**Method 2**

If you look at the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

Which means below also should work for you

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name='value' ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 10;
```

Try one of them which suits you and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Hi @Dasun the first method returns "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery" It is a new mysql feature?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's the issue, let me work on it. try the method 2 which will work for sure.

Comment: second method shows this: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 10' at line 1
 (i tried before without sucess).

Comment: thanks a lot @Dasun second method works. I can't give you a check because do it before with rizon answer :(.

Comment: since you are new here, you can always up-vote(up arrow) the answer which helps you and accept the answer which solved your problem(tick). down-vote(down arrow) the answers which are fake.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any input into your tables schema, but here is an idea of something that could work:

```
UPDATE users SET firstname='michael' WHERE id >= (SELECT MAX(id)-10 FROM users);
```

Comment: partially works @sixeightzero for some reason the query do 24 row updates instead 10.